Is there a way to differentiate a user added "Off" and Adobe auto-added "Off" for radio buttons in the fields of a PDF doc from pdftk dump_data_fields
I am using the php-pdftk getDataFields() method to get the fields from a PDF form that is submitted to my PHP page. This maps directly to the dump_data_fields option of pdftk, and the same issue can be seen when running pdftk [PDF file] dump_data_fields
If the PDF form has a field that is a group of Radio Buttons, with options "Yes" and "No", the FDF contains a third option "Off" for that field.
If the PDF form has a field that is a group of Radio Buttons, with options "On" and "Off", the FDF only contains those two options for that field.
Is there any way for me to know whether the "Off" option was added automatically (per example 1), or was actually on the form (per example 2)?
Alternatively (if it's added as part of getDataFields()), is there any way to prevent the "Off" option being automatically added in the first place?

Looks like I got confused when I wrote the question! I said FDF but that was wrong, it's the getDataFields function which maps to pdftk's dump_data_fields option that I'm looking at. I will edit the question now

For my question we can ignore the single button "groups". Let's add another double button group, then change it into a triple button group by adding an option that has the value "Off". When doing dump_data_fields, both the double button group and the triple button group look the same I think? I want to know how if I can tell whether it is a double button group (with no "Off" option) or a triple button group (with an "Off" option). The reason is that I am writing code to convert a PDF form to an HTML form, so I want the HTML form to look the same as the PDF form. Thanks :)

I agree, however I have a whole pile of PDF forms to convert and some of them have radios with an "Off" option, so I'm trying to figure out if I can handle it in the program, or if I will have to go through each PDF manually to see which ones really have an "Off" option. The one I came across initially was a radio button where they had to choose if a machine was on, on stand by, or off, and it was implemented with radios having one option "On", one option "Standby", and one option "Off".

Unfortunately I don't have the ability to create PDFs, but if you create a PDF which has one radio field with a double group "On" and "Standby", and one radio field with a triple group "On", "Standby", and "Off", that would be a good example.

Also just to re-iterate, the issue is not about what a user might have chosen, the issue is about finding out what the field setup is so I can replicate the form in HTML.

If  in the example PDF I described I can tell from dump_data_fields which is a double group and which is a triple group, I should be able to use that knowledge for the historic set.

So looking at that example, Group1 and Group2 seem to be identical in the output of dump_data_fields, so there is no way for me to tell whether it was a double or a triple group right? `---
FieldType: Button
FieldName: Group1
FieldFlags: 32768
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: Off
FieldStateOption: On
FieldStateOption: Standby
FieldType: Button
FieldName: Group2
FieldFlags: 32768
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: Off
FieldStateOption: On
FieldStateOption: Standby`
